# Integrate react-native-navigation with react-native-callkit in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I am trying to to integrate RNN (React Native Navigation) with RNCK (React Native CallKit) in iOS.
The problem is that each of them requires a unique setup in Xcode project's AppDelegate.

Both of them need `jsCodeLocation`:

```
NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
```

RNN setup:

```
[ReactNativeNavigation bootstrap:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

RNCK setup:

```
RNCallKit *rncallkit = [[RNCallKit alloc] init];
RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                          moduleProvider:^{ return @[rncallkit]; }
                                           launchOptions:launchOptions];
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                 moduleName:@"MyApp"
                                          initialProperties:nil];
```

I see [this (outdated) issue in RNCK repo](https://github.com/ianlin/react-native-callkit/issues/16), which leads to [this (also outdated) issue](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/1884) and both talk about RNN 1, while in RNN 2 this setup is simplified and I don't see a proper way to integrate both frameworks in one project except forking the RNN and adding a separate initialiser that will receive `moduleProvider`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RNN has an additional `bootstrap` method that takes a delegate object parameter (which implements `RNNBridgeManagerDelegate`) that allows you to inject extra modules.

Here's an example of how you can bootstrap RNN with the app delegate itself set as the delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  [ReactNativeNavigation bootstrap:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions bridgeManagerDelegate:self];
  return YES;
}
```

You can then implement the delegate method and return the `RNCallKit` object:

```
- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge {
  RNCallKit *rncallkit = [[RNCallKit alloc] init];
  return @[rncallkit];
}
```

Comment: I'm not an iOS developer, could you also please tell me where I should be putting the second snippet of code? I get the following warning under bridgeManagerDelegate:self
`Sending 'AppDelegate *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<RNNBridgeManagerDelegate>'`

Comment: @platonish `extraModulesForBridge` needs to be implemented in whatever interface that you set to be your delegate. In the example I set it to `self` which is the `AppDelegate` itself, so `extraModulesForBridge` needs to be in your `AppDelegate` in this case. Regarding the warning - you need to declare that the object conform to the delegate protocol, example for this specific case - `AppDelegate <RNNBridgeManagerDelegate>`. you can read more about it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html